# Pass callback function as prop to a different route using react-router

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-router

I'm attempting to pass a function to be used as a callback in a different route. I know it's possible to do this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const FirstPage = props => {
    let history = useHistory();

    const someEventHandler = event => {
       history.push({
           pathname: '/secondpage',
           state: { detail: 'some_value' }
       });
    };

};
```

but I get this error when I try pass a  callback function like this:

my code with callback:

```
    const someEventHandler = event => {
       history.push({
           pathname: '/secondpage',
           state: { my_callback: selectedPlaylist }
       });
    };
```

error:

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': selectedPlaylist => {
       ....
  }
```

Is this just something that cannot be done since it's a reference to a function and not necessarily state? Is there a workaround? I'm not able to find any resources similar to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the logic behind to pass a function by router state? What the function does?

Comment: the event handler is tied to a button component onClick and the callback function just accepts a list and console logs the list that it gets from the second page component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) says:

> The state object can be anything that can be serialized. Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception. If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use sessionStorage and/or localStorage.

A `function` cannot be cloned or serialized. What you want to do is better be passed as `props`. Using `state` object on `history` is very weird. Example:

```
function FirstPage() {
  // ...
  return (
    <>
      <Link to='/secondpage'>go to second page</Link>
      <Route
        path='/secondpage'
        render={() => <SecondPage myCallback={selectedPlaylist}}
      />
   </>
  );
}
```

If you expand more on what you want to accomplish, it'll get easier to help.